# octave/matlab: write file as plain text

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

Say I have a matrix

```
test =
{
  [1,1] = one
  [1,2] = two
  [1,3] = three
}
```

I want to write it into a file. I do

```
`save myfile.txt test`
```

But when I open the file with Notepad++ for example, I get `MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, written by Octave 3.2.4, 2013-07-11 15:23:20 UTC` and then a bunch of `NUL` `SOH` `BS` `ACK`, etc...

Is there a way to just write the matrix into a plain text file so that it would look like:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: use `'-ascii'` flag for saving

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-ascii`  flag. From the `save` [documentation](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/save.html):

> **-ascii**
>
> Save a single matrix in a text file without header or any other information.